# Access UICollectionView cell at given index path

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I got a collection view with some sections and some custom cells in each section. Now I want the user to be able to select a cell by entering its index path in two text fields (each an integer). After a button is tapped, the cell at the entered index path changes its label. How would you do that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the datasource model data and then tell the collection view to reload that cell...

Answer (score 1):

When the user taps the button, you could change the model (your data array, CoreData stuff or whatever) which is used to fill your cells with data to reflect the new label, then call [reloadItemsAtIndexPaths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:) to notify the UI about the need to reload your specific cell. At that point, your collection view's data source method [cellForItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:) is called to build the new cell.